Python typing for a generic instance method decorator
I am creating a generic decorator for an instance method:
def my_dec(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("do something")
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

All works fine, except typing. When I type it as follows:
def my_dec(
    func: Callable[[*Tuple[Any, ...]], Any]
) -> Callable[[*Tuple[Any, ...]], Any]:
    def wrapper(
        self: Any,
        *args: Any,
        **kwargs: Any
    ) -> Any:
        print("do something")
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

When I use the decorator I receive errors from mypy such as:
 Argument 1 to "my_dec" has incompatible type 
"Callable[[datetime, datetime | str, str | NoInput], float | None]"; 
expected  "Callable[[VarArg(Any)], Any]"  [arg-type]

Shouldn't these be allowed with the set of Any? What to do to fix?
Obviously this cannot be function specific, the decorator is applied to many different functions.

Related? Specifying *args for a Callable type hint

The (square) brackets in your snippet are imbalanced, please fix that. mypy behaviour is correct: the decorator you defined can (only) be applied to def fn(*args: Something) function, not to a function with specific number of params. Only (*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) is special and treated as an arbitrary function. You probably want to read about typing.ParamSpec.

Thanks very much for pointing in the right direction. Yes, the solution was PEP 612
